# Limit dropdown results in generic UpdateView

Tags: django

Working on my first Django project! I have an UpdateView and I want to limit the dropdown results of program_code so it only shows items that the user owns. I think I have to pass kwargs to the view to limit the queryset but not sure where to begin or how to go about doing that. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

View:

```
class ContactsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Contact
    fields = ['first_name1', 'last_name1','address1','address2','city','province','postal_code','country','active_status','program_code']
    template_name = 'contacts/contacts_form.html'
    success_message = "Contact was updated successfully"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        contact = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == contact.author:
            return True
        return False
```

model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='First Name', null=True)
    last_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Last Name', null=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Address 1', null=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Address 2', null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='City', null=True)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PROVINCE_CHOICES, default='Ontario', verbose_name='Province')
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=7, verbose_name='Postal Code', null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Country', null=True, default='Canada')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    program_code = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.first_name1 + ' ' + self.last_name1

    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse('contacts-home')
```

template form:

```
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-2 mt-2">Update Contact</legend>
            <p>Created by: {{ object.author }},  Last Updated: {{ object.date_posted }}</p>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Update</button>

            <div class="mt-4"><a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" href="{% url 'contacts-delete' object.id %}" role="button">Delete Contact</a></div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
# form
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       user = kwargs.pop('user', None)  # This will be sent from View
       super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['program_code'].queryset = Program.objects.filter(owner=user)

   class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['first_name1', 'last_name1','address1','address2','city','province','postal_code','country','active_status','program_code']

#view

class ContactsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Contact
    from_class = ContactForm
    template_name = 'contacts/contacts_form.html'
    success_message = "Contact was updated successfully"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):  
        # Sending user information to Form
        kwargs = super(ContactsUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Here in the View, we are overriding the [get_form_kwargs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) method to pass current `user` information to the Form. And inside the form, we are overriding the `__init__` method to catch the `user` data sent from View, and use it to override default `queryset` value of the field `program_code`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense to me! - I am getting the error "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'". Could it be because my Contact model uses author instead of user?

Comment: Not sure why, but are you calling the form instance like `ContactForm(user)` anywhere in the code? Also please add the full stactrace the question please